# Is possible to implement this function with a single django ORM query?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm making an aggregate report of stores, categories and customers for an ecommerce. Basically, I'm trying to achieve what this function does:

```py
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField, F, Sum
from .models import Order


def get_report_data(stores, categories, customers):
    result = []
    for store in stores:
        for category in categories:
            for customer in customers:
                total = Order.objects.filter(
                    store=store,
                    orderitem__product__category=category,
                    customer=customer,
                ).aggregate(
                    total=Sum(
                        ExpressionWrapper(
                            F("orderitem__product__price") * F("orderitem__quantity"),
                            output_field=DecimalField(),
                        )
                    )
                )["total"]
                result.append([store, customer, category, total])
        return result
```

Obviously, this is efficiently poor and I'm trying to turn this function into a query. I've tried the following, but I know I'm missing the mark by A LOT.

```py
total = (
    Order.objects.filter(
        store__in=stores,
        customer__in=customers,
        orderitem__product__category__in=categories,
    )
    .values("store", "orderitem__product__category")
    .annotate(
        total=Sum(
            ExpressionWrapper(
                F("orderitem__product__price") * F("orderitem__quantity"),
                output_field=DecimalField(),
            )
        )
    )
)
```

How should I proceed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: are  you going to use that query in django-rest-framework or normal django function or class based views Query? can you please specify more?

Comment: I'm going to use it in DRF. But there's no need to enter in serialization proccess :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use DRF function based views you don't need serializers. check the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/ and try out as normal django view function with drf @api_view decorator

replace the following view function with your data query and pass as a data context key value in Response({})

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

Comment: I know that. But that's not going to solve the main problem: efficiency. As I said, I need a query to make this efficiently acceptable.

Comment: by efficiently what you actually mean?

Comment: Time consumption.